# Handle multiple check-box in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, use-state, react-state

Well, what I am trying to do is I want to create a Filter-Screen in react-native like those we see in Flipkart, Myntra, or Swiggy. I am successfully able to make it but the thing is the code I have written is way too long because of the number of checkboxes I have used and also I had to write the numbers of `{useState}` to handle the multiple checkboxes.  So is there any way to short down my code, the code is given below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, TouchableOpacity, Text, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import { Checkbox, RadioButton } from 'react-native-paper';

const Filter = ({ route, navigation }) => {
    const [checked1, setChecked1] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked2, setChecked2] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked3, setChecked3] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked4, setChecked4] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked5, setChecked5] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked6, setChecked6] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked7, setChecked7] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked8, setChecked8] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked9, setChecked9] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked10, setChecked10] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked11, setChecked11] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked12, setChecked12] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked13, setChecked13] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked14, setChecked14] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked15, setChecked15] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked16, setChecked16] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked17, setChecked17] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked18, setChecked18] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked19, setChecked19] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked20, setChecked20] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked21, setChecked21] = React.useState(false);
    const [checked22, setChecked22] = React.useState(false);   


    const [radioChecked, setRadioChecked] = React.useState('first');
    // All your menu options go here. 
    const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = React.useState([
        { id: '1', name: 'Sort', },
        { id: '2', name: 'Cuisines', },
        { id: '3', name: 'Offers & More', },
        { id: '4', name: 'Ideal for Viewing Distance dsfhj fdsfjj ', },
        { id: '5', name: 'Age', },
        { id: '6', name: 'Price', },
        { id: '7', name: 'Age', },
        { id: '8', name: 'Price', },
        { id: '9', name: 'Age', },
        { id: '10', name: 'Price', },
        { id: '11', name: 'Age', },
        { id: '12', name: 'Price', },
        { id: '13', name: 'Age', },
        { id: '14', name: 'Price', },
        { id: '15', name: 'Age', },
        { id: '16', name: 'Price', },
        { id: '17', name: 'Test', },
        { id: '18', name: 'last', },

    ])
    // this holds the keys of the menuItems for the view to know which category is currently being rendered. 
    const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState('1')
    return (
        <>

            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingVertical: 5 }}>
                <View style={{ marginRight: 15, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.goBack() }}>
                        <Entypo name={'cross'} style={{ marginRight: 12, marginLeft: 5, }} size={30} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#000' }}>Sort/Filter</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ marginRight: 15, marginLeft: 15, paddingVertical: 5, }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('Clear All Pressed')} >
                        <Text style={{ color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>CLEAR ALL</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.content}>
                <View style={styles.menuColumn}>
                    <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic" showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                        {menuItems.map(
                            (item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <TouchableOpacity key={item.id} onPress={() => setSelectedItem(item.id)} style={[styles.menuItem, item.id === selectedItem ? styles.selectedMenuItem : null]}>
                                        <Text numberOfLines={2} style={styles.menuItemText}>{item.name}</Text>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                )
                            }
                        )
                        }
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.settingsColumn}>
                    <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic" showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                        {
                            selectedItem === '1' &&
                            <View style={styles.settingsView} >
                                <Text style={{ textTransform: 'uppercase' }}>Show Restaurants By</Text>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <RadioButton
                                        value="first"
                                        status={radioChecked === 'first' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => setRadioChecked('first')}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Relevance</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <RadioButton
                                        value="second"
                                        status={radioChecked === 'second' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => setRadioChecked('second')}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Delivery Time</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <RadioButton
                                        value="third"
                                        status={radioChecked === 'third' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => setRadioChecked('third')}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Rating</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <RadioButton
                                        value="fourth"
                                        status={radioChecked === 'fourth' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => setRadioChecked('fourth')}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Cost: Low to High</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <RadioButton
                                        value="fifth"
                                        status={radioChecked === 'fifth' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => setRadioChecked('fifth')}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Cost: High to Low</Text>
                                </View>

                            </View>
                        }
                        {
                            selectedItem === '2' &&
                            <View style={styles.settingsView} >
                                <Text>CUISINES</Text>
                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked1 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked1(!checked1);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>American</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked2 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked2(!checked2);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Andhra</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked3 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked3(!checked3);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Arabian</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked4 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked4(!checked4);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Asian</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked5 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked5(!checked5);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Barbecue</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked6 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked6(!checked6);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Beverages</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked7 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked7(!checked7);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Biryani</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked8 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked8(!checked8);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Chinese</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked9 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked9(!checked9);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Continental</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked10 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked10(!checked10);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Combo</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked11 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked11(!checked11);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Desserts</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked12 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked12(!checked12);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Europian</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked13 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked13(!checked13);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Fast Food</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked14 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked14(!checked14);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Grill</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked15 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked15(!checked15);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Healthy Food</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked16 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked16(!checked16);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Hydrabadi</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked17 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked17(!checked17);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Ice Cream</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked18 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked18(!checked18);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Indian</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked19 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked19(!checked19);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Italian</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked20 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked20(!checked20);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Juices</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked21 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked21(!checked21);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Kebabs</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <Checkbox
                                        status={checked22 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => {
                                            setChecked22(!checked22);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Maxican</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        }
                        {
                            selectedItem === '3' &&
                            <View style={styles.settingsView} >
                                <Text>Anything can go here</Text>
                            </View>
                        }
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                {/* <View style={{ marginRight: 15, marginLeft: 15, paddingVertical: 5, flex: 0.5 }}>
                    <Button title="Clear Filters" />
                </View> */}
                <View style={{ marginRight: 15, marginLeft: 15, paddingVertical: 5, flex: 0.5 }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnDRed} onPress={() => { navigation.goBack() }}>
                        <Text style={{ color: '#fff', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 16 }}>APPLY</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    content: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flex: 1,
    },
    menuColumn: {
        flex: .35,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        backgroundColor: '#dedede',
    },
    menuItem: {
        // flex: 1,
        flex: 0,
        //height:hp(8.5),
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        // alignItems: 'flex-start',
        // borderWidth:1,
    },
    selectedMenuItem: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        color: '#162da2',
    },

    menuItemText: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        paddingVertical: 16,
    },
    // value column -right
    settingsColumn: {
        flex: .65,
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    btnDRed: {
        paddingVertical: 7,
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 7,
        backgroundColor: "#ff0000",

    },

});

export default Filter;
```

Answer (score 1):

To Short down my code, I have made use of `{useState} and <Flatlist>`  in my code like given below but it is giving me an error that "the renderList or something called virtualization list cannot be nested inside the scrollView.." something like this so what should I do now is there any solution to this :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, TouchableOpacity, Text, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import { Checkbox, RadioButton } from 'react-native-paper';


 const data = [
     { id: 1, txt: 'American', isChecked: false },
     { id: 2, txt: 'Andhra', isChecked: false },
     { id: 3, txt: 'Arabian', isChecked: false },
     { id: 4, txt: 'Asian', isChecked: false },
     { id: 5, txt: 'Barbecue', isChecked: false },
     { id: 6, txt: 'Beverages', isChecked: false },
     { id: 7, txt: 'Biryani', isChecked: false },
     { id: 8, txt: 'American', isChecked: false },
     { id: 9, txt: 'Andhra', isChecked: false },
     { id: 10, txt: 'Arabian', isChecked: false },
     { id: 11, txt: 'Asian', isChecked: false },
     { id: 12, txt: 'Barbecue', isChecked: false },
     { id: 13, txt: 'Beverages', isChecked: false },
     { id: 14, txt: 'Biryani', isChecked: false },
 ];

 const renderFlatList = (renderData) => {
     return (
         <FlatList
             data={renderData}
             renderItem={({ item }) => (
                 <View
                     style={{
                         flexDirection: 'row',
                         flex: 1,
                         justifyContent: 'space-between',
                         alignItems: 'center'
                     }}>
                     <Checkbox
                         value={item.isChecked}
                         onChange={() => {
                             handleChange(item.id);
                         }}
                     />
                     <Text>{item.txt}</Text>
                 </View>
             )}
         />
     );
 };


const Filter = ({ route, navigation }) => {
     const [cuisines, setCuisines] = useState(data);
    
     const handleChange = (id) => {
         let temp = cuisines.map((cuisine) => {
             if (id === cuisine.id) {
                 return { ...cuisine, isChecked: !cuisine.isChecked };
             }
             return cuisine;
         });
         setCuisines(temp);
     };

     let selected = cuisines.filter((cuisine) => cuisine.isChecked);


    const [radioChecked, setRadioChecked] = React.useState('first');
    // All your menu options go here. 
    const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = React.useState([
        { id: '1', name: 'Sort', },
        { id: '2', name: 'Cuisines', },
        { id: '3', name: 'Offers & More', },
        { id: '4', name: 'Ideal for Viewing Distance dsfhj fdsfjj ', },
        { id: '5', name: 'Age', },
        { id: '6', name: 'Price', },
        { id: '7', name: 'Age', },
        { id: '8', name: 'Price', },
        { id: '9', name: 'Age', },
        { id: '10', name: 'Price', },
        { id: '11', name: 'Age', },
        { id: '12', name: 'Price', },
        { id: '13', name: 'Age', },
        { id: '14', name: 'Price', },
        { id: '15', name: 'Age', },
        { id: '16', name: 'Price', },
        { id: '17', name: 'Test', },
        { id: '18', name: 'last', },

    ])
    // this holds the keys of the menuItems for the view to know which category is currently being rendered. 
    const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState('1')
    return (
        <>

            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingVertical: 5 }}>
                <View style={{ marginRight: 15, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.goBack() }}>
                        <Entypo name={'cross'} style={{ marginRight: 12, marginLeft: 5, }} size={30} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#000' }}>Sort/Filter</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ marginRight: 15, marginLeft: 15, paddingVertical: 5, }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('Clear All Pressed')} >
                        <Text style={{ color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>CLEAR ALL</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.content}>
                <View style={styles.menuColumn}>
                    <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic" showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                        {menuItems.map(
                            (item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <TouchableOpacity key={item.id} onPress={() => setSelectedItem(item.id)} style={[styles.menuItem, item.id === selectedItem ? styles.selectedMenuItem : null]}>
                                        <Text numberOfLines={2} style={styles.menuItemText}>{item.name}</Text>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                )
                            }
                        )
                        }
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.settingsColumn}>
                    <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic" showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                        {
                            selectedItem === '1' &&
                            <View style={styles.settingsView} >
                                <Text style={{ textTransform: 'uppercase' }}>Show Restaurants By</Text>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <RadioButton
                                        value="first"
                                        status={radioChecked === 'first' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => setRadioChecked('first')}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Relevance</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <RadioButton
                                        value="second"
                                        status={radioChecked === 'second' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => setRadioChecked('second')}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Delivery Time</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <RadioButton
                                        value="third"
                                        status={radioChecked === 'third' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => setRadioChecked('third')}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Rating</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <RadioButton
                                        value="fourth"
                                        status={radioChecked === 'fourth' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => setRadioChecked('fourth')}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Cost: Low to High</Text>
                                </View>

                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <RadioButton
                                        value="fifth"
                                        status={radioChecked === 'fifth' ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}
                                        onPress={() => setRadioChecked('fifth')}
                                    />
                                    <Text>Cost: High to Low</Text>
                                </View>

                            </View>
                        }
                        {
                            selectedItem === '2' &&
                            <View style={styles.settingsView} >
                                <Text>CUISINES</Text>
                                <View>{renderFlatList(cuisines)}</View>   
                            </View>
                        }
                        {
                            selectedItem === '3' &&
                            <View style={styles.settingsView} >
                                <Text>Anything can go here</Text>
                            </View>
                        }
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                {/* <View style={{ marginRight: 15, marginLeft: 15, paddingVertical: 5, flex: 0.5 }}>
                    <Button title="Clear Filters" />
                </View> */}
                <View style={{ marginRight: 15, marginLeft: 15, paddingVertical: 5, flex: 0.5 }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnDRed} onPress={() => { navigation.goBack() }}>
                        <Text style={{ color: '#fff', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 16 }}>APPLY</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    content: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flex: 1,
    },
    menuColumn: {
        flex: .35,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        backgroundColor: '#dedede',
    },
    menuItem: {
        // flex: 1,
        flex: 0,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    selectedMenuItem: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        color: '#162da2',
    },

    menuItemText: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 10,
        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        paddingVertical: 16,
    },
    // value column -right
    settingsColumn: {
        flex: .65,
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    btnDRed: {
        paddingVertical: 7,
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 7,
        backgroundColor: "#ff0000",

    },

});

export default Filter;
```